# global extern const clarification

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants, extern

Is declaring extern const or just extern the same thing in a header file? Also will both give external linkage?

globals.cpp

```
#include <string>

extern const std::string foo = "bar";
```

globals.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include <iostream>

extern const std::string foo;

#endif  /* GLOBALS_H */
```

OR

globals.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include <iostream>

extern std::string foo;

#endif  /* GLOBALS_H */
```

Both compiles and run fine, both give same address when used in multiple files, which one is more correct?

Comment: It's no a question of which is "more correct;" one of them is actually incorrect and will result in errors if foo is actually used. See my answer below.

Comment: I did cout foo.c_str() in other files, still compiles and runs fine.. weird.

Comment: that seems wrong. Either there's something more complex going on or your compiler/linker aren't checking the declaration very well. What happens if you try to modify foo from one of those files? e.g. Does foo.clear(); compile okay? If it does, does it still compile if you use the "const" version in the header? (If it does still compile then it's probably not the header's declaration that the files are seeing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is correct,

```
//globals.h

extern const std::string foo; //Consistent
```

Consistent!

Comment: in such case, where should I initialize foo?

Comment: In the `.cpp` file; also, `extern` is not needed in `.cpp` file.

Comment: I am sorry but I am trying to get it right, will sth like `foo = "abs" ` in `.cpp` file be valid? if not then how should I initialize it. One more thing, is `extern` only used with classes?

Comment: No. `const std::string foo = "abs";` at the same namespace level.

Answer (score 1):

You can give const external linkage, as in your example, but it's still non-modifiable (constant).
P.S. you need to include `<string>`, not `<iostream>`

P.P.S. If I wasn't clear, you can't redefine const-ness. This will not compile:

```
extern std::string foo;
extern const std::string foo = "bar";
```

Comment: That is what intended. But which header file is correct? Reason I put iostream so that it includes both std::string and std::cout, more convenient I guess.

Comment: what do you mean, which is correct? Both are correct, provided you use const or non-const consistently. You can't define const in one place and non-const in another.

Comment: iostream doesn't have to include string header

Comment: @Kaizoku, just because it compiles does not make it correct, nor mean that it will work properly or even compile in other environments. As a simple example, "int *p = NULL; *p = 10;" may compile fine (unless the compiler is clever enough to catch it) but will crash if you run it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is

```
extern const std::string foo;
```

`foo` is a constant string in the source file it is defined in, so the `extern` declaration should indicate this too and allow the compiler to catch instances where code within source file where that header is included may try to modify `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason they both compile fine is that you are not actually using foo, so it doesn't matter whether the linker can find foo or not (it never tries to). (Or your compiler/linker is rubbish. :) )

The consistent header is fine. The one missing the const is not and will/should result in errors if something tries to use foo.

If you make some file (not globals.cpp) which includes globals.h and tries to use foo (e.g. just add a line with "foo.c_str();" into a function) then you'll get a link error because no `const std::string foo` could be found.

This is how it has to be, too. The header is telling anything that wants to use foo that it can only read it, not modify it. Things which include the globals.h header have no idea of what is inside globals.cpp; if you want them to treat an object as const you have to put that information in a file which they include.

Answer (score 0):

For C language, declare actual const in a .c file and use 'extern' for it in a header (.h) file. This should be as usual as we do when declaring a global variable.